# ASP.NET Zero not mapping Paid Editions

Tags: objectmapper, aspnetboilerplate

I have recently started using the ASP.NET Zero system and noticed that when I'm attempting to change an edition to a paid edition, it does not show it when I go to edit the edition again. In my database, I have the other values that I entered so the edition is saving correctly. When editing the edition, the radio button will still say "Free."

I noticed that the **EditionAppService.cs** file utilizes the `ObjectMapper` to map from `SubscribableEditions` to `EditionEditDto`. When the `SubscribableEdition` enters the mapper, it has the values for `Monthly` and `Annual` prices. When it exits the mapper as the `EditionEditDto`, both values are `null`. Somehow, the `ObjectMapper` isn't pulling over these values.

I have attached two pictures below. The first shows the `SubscribableEdition` that has the `AnnualPrice` and the `MonthlyPrice`.

[image: SubscribableEdition]

When I take the next step in the second picture to see the results of the `ObjectMapper`, you will see that it no longer has a value for either of those fields in the `EditionEditDto`.

[image: EditionEditDto]

This results in the edition appearing to be Free when editing it. I thought that maybe the fact that it was a nullable `Decimal` was the problem. But once I removed that and converted it to a normal decimal, it filled in the prices with zeroes instead of `null` values. When I downloaded and completed the PhoneBook tutorial, I noticed that project also had the same issue of the `Edition` not saving.

I am trying to figure out why the mapper isn't mapping the values over to the `EditionEditDto` correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to a missing map in **CustomDtoMapper.cs** that will be added in v5.1:

`- configuration.CreateMap<EditionEditDto, SubscribableEdition>();`
`+ configuration.CreateMap<EditionEditDto, SubscribableEdition>().ReverseMap();`